# How to remove the query string from the wordpress url using .htaccess rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, query-string

I want to remove the query string from the wordpress url.
URL:
http://domain.com/our-homes-storey/?storey=40
I want to change that url from the below url:
http://domain.com/our-homes-storey/locationname

Comment: Just check your permalink setting. there is no need for htaccess rules

Comment: In back-end (admin panel) you have to set permalink to post name in settings tab.  it will automatically create .htaccess for you

Comment: This is not a page url. This is custom url. So I want to change that url.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Wordpress Admin - Settings - Permalinks

And set your permalinks to be one of the formats you want, or create your own.

Comment: This is not a page url. This is custom url. So I want to change that url.

Comment: You need to make your question a bit more clearer. I don't understand what you're trying to do now. What's generating the store parameter? Can we see some code?

Comment: Please find the link: http://melbournebuilders.demo.netsmartz.us/our-homes/ and click on the particular storey after that generate the url: http://melbournebuilders.demo.netsmartz.us/our-homes-storey/?storey=40. So i want to change the url: http://melbournebuilders.demo.netsmartz.us/our-homes-storey/locationname

Comment: What's generating the store parameter? Can we see the code that's generating those links?

Comment: <option value="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'storey',$hmrow->home_id, get_permalink(295) ); ?>"> <?php echo $hmrow->home_name;?></option>

Comment: If it's getting permalink, then it must be using Wordpresses permalink functions. Have you tried setting your permalinks in the Admin and seeing if it makes any changes?